# Sum Notation and frac in Math Environment

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I have a problem I can't deal with.

I want to draw the equation which is in the below picture at Latex.
[image]

However, the things above and below the addition symbol are not rendering as I would like.

```
 \sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{8} \bigg(\Tilde{E}_{x,i}-\Big \langle \Tilde{E}_{x} \Big \rangle\bigg)^{\!2} } {a}}
```

```
\begin{align}
\sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{8} \bigg(\Tilde{E}_{x,i}-\Big \langle \Tilde{E}_{x} \Big \rangle\bigg)^{\!2} } {a}}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using too big delimiters. You might use `\sum\limits`, but that's not the best way, in my opinion.

Here are five realizations of the formula (thanks to yarchik for suggesting the last one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\sigma_{x}&=\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{8} \bigg(\Tilde{E}_{x,i}-
  \Big \langle \Tilde{E}_{x} \Big \rangle\bigg)^{\!2} } {a}}
\tag{your input}
\\
\sigma_{x} &= \sqrt{
  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^8 \bigl(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\bigl\langle \tilde{E}_x\bigr\rangle\bigr)^2}{a}
}
\tag{slightly better}
\\
\sigma_{x} &= \sqrt{
  \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^8 \bigl(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\bigl\langle \tilde{E}_x\bigr\rangle\bigr)^2}
       {a}
}
\tag{slightly worse}
\\
\sigma_{x} &= \sqrt{
  \frac{1}{a}\biggl(\,
    \sum_{i=1}^8 \bigl(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\bigl\langle \tilde{E}_x\bigr\rangle\bigr)^2
  \biggr)
}
\tag{better?}
\\
\sigma_{x} &= \sqrt{
  \frac{1}{a}
    \sum_{i=1}^8 \bigl(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\bigl\langle \tilde{E}_x\bigr\rangle\bigr)^2
}
\tag{much better?}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\Tilde` and `\tilde` are completely equivalent. In (very) older version of `amsmath`, capitalized command were needed for stacking accents, but later the stacking problem was solved in a different way, so the capitalized commands remained for back compatibility.

[image]

Comment: In the last line the outer parentheses are not needed, are they?

Comment: @yarchik Good remark! I'll add one!

Answer (score 8):

With your `\Tilde` changed into a standard `\tilde`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

You want
\[
\sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{8}\limits \biggl(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\Bigl\langle \tilde{E}_{x} \Bigr \rangle\biggr)^{\!2} } {a}}
\]
or rather
\[
\sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{ \sum_{i=1}^{8}\limits \left(\tilde{E}_{x,i}-\left\langle \tilde{E}_{x} \right \rangle\right)^{\!2} } {a}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i want to write the equation like \begin{equation}..... \end equation.  When I use \[ and \]  the compiler give an error.

Comment: @mathali Not `[ ... ]`, but `\[ ... \]` (with backslash). You can also use the code inside in the `equation` environment.

Comment: Just for information: `\Tilde` does the same as `\tilde`. In (very) older version of `amsmath`, capitalized command were needed for stacking accents, but later the stacking problem was solved in a different way, so the capitalized commands remained for back compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Adding another solution to @egreg’s list, allow me to suggest:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
    \sigma_{x}
    =
    \biggl(
        \frac{1}{a}
        \sum_{i=1}^{8} 
        \bigl(
            \tilde{E}_{x,i}
            -
            \bigl\langle \tilde{E}_{x} \bigr\rangle
        \bigr)^{2}
    \biggr)^{\!\! 1/2}
    \tag{best}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]